# Seeking temporal Landsat imagery

Tags: data, landsat

It's been a while since I've dealt with optical imagery. I need to perform a land cover classification at mid-latitudes using several LANDSAT scenes. I've noticed that some online tools are still selling the imagery, but I was under the impression that the archive was now offered up at no cost.

What is the best/easiest way to obtain temporal Landsat imagery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am in Canada so if I need this  imagery I can get it free at [Geobase.](http://www.geobase.ca/geobase/en/index.html)
Elsewhere you should be able to download from [USGS](http://landsat.usgs.gov/Landsat_Search_and_Download.php) direct. You will need to register on both sites.  Here are [NASA](http://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/where.html) links to download free Landsat data.

Answer (score 7):

**Bulk Download**

One can also follow the instructions given at
[Landsat Scenes: Bulk Download](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/order/bulkdownload), part of USGS' [EarthExplorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov) web-service.

After selecting the scenes of interest within from either the [USGS Global Visualisation Viewer](http://glovis.usgs.gov/) or [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), one has to save/create the scene IDs of interest as a list (each ID entry should be a single line) in a pure *.txt* file.
More about this USGS' respective Q&A (FAQ): [How do I submit a bulk download request for Landsat data?](http://landsat.usgs.gov/bulk_download_request.php)

It only takes then to upload the *.txt* file in the above mentioned page (web-service) and get as a result down-loadable scenes (links) or submit a Bulk Download order which can be completed by using the [Bulk Download Application](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/bulk/) (see the [Help Documentation](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/Final1282015bdahelp.pdf)).

**Notes**

- the [GLCF](http://glcf.umiacs.umd.edu/) maintains a small subset of the entire Landsat archive, prior to 2006
- **[update]** there is, however, <s>(currently?)</s> a **restriction** in downloading **up to <s>100</s> 500 Landsat scenes** per *Bulk Download Order*

Answer (score 6):

You can also get it from the [Global Land Cover Facility](http://glcfapp.glcf.umd.edu:8080/esdi/index.jsp). No registration required.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Check out [USGS' EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), most are free including all of LANDSAT's archive.  You need to register to download data.

Answer (score 3):

USGS is what I use. 
Note that high quality processing can be achieved in GRASS, I encourage you to carry out atmospheric correction. There are a lot of "primers" out there about calculating NDVI etc which completely overlook atmospheric effects. You can achieve quantitative analysis this way.

Answer (score 3):

I find the USGS NewEarthExplorer to be the easiest way to download Landsat scenes. As I discuss in [a blog post](http://blog.rtwilson.com/finally-a-nice-way-to-download-satellite-images/), it has a far more 'modern' interface which makes it easier to select appropriate images for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The USGS have been recommending using [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) (EE) because it has the most development resources right now.

They offer the **USGS Inventory Service** as a machine-to-machine SOAP API for communicating with EE for querying their archive for scenes. This way, you can also order scenes for processing to Level 1 georegistered radiance products, and also get the weblink to download them.

A Python tool is being developed here [LANDSAT-Download](https://github.com/olivierhagolle/LANDSAT-Download)
 where you can provide the Python script a list of WRS-2 target sites, and it will download all the available products `.tar.gz` for the year

Answer (score 1):

For Landsat 8 imagery, I've found the [landsat-util](https://github.com/developmentseed/landsat-util) tool to be the easiest to use.

Answer (score 1):

AWS hosts Landsat scenes on S3

https://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/landsat/

To do land cover classification, you could also consider using Sentinel 2 data. Sentinel 2A has been launched a few months ago, its 10m resolution with 13 spectral bands. The Copernicus program grants full open access to the sentinel data:

https://scihub.copernicus.eu/

Here is an explorer for finding sentinel data

http://satcat.eoproc.com/cat-01/dev-online.html?&config=demo-01