# Seeking LANDSAT for state of New Mexico

Tags: data, landsat, united-states

I am looking for a website that allows me to download free LANDSAT for all of the State of New Mexico. I need them to perform my work on RUSLE and need LANDSAT for c factor.

Does anyone suggest of a good website?

The one I have download is the GLCF: Earth Science Data Interface from the University of Maryland. I have some LANDSAT 2006 that covers the southern new mexico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several good sources including the following:

[WELD](http://weld.cr.usgs.gov/)

> WELD generates 30-meter composites of Landsat 7 Enhanced Thematic
>   Mapper Plus (ETM+) terrain corrected (Level 1T) mosaics at weekly,
>   monthly, seasonal and annual periods for the conterminous United
>   States (CONUS) and Alaska. These mosaics provide consistent data that
>   can be used to derive land cover as well as geo-physical and
>   biophysical products for regional assessment of surface dynamics and
>   to study Earth system functioning.

[Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), a familiar USGS site.

One of my favorite sites for Landsat data.  I especially like the download interface.

[GloVis](http://glovis.usgs.gov/), yet another familiar USGS site.

If everything continues to go well, Landsat 8 will be providing providing data to the public in the near future.  From the [USGS](http://landsat.usgs.gov/L8_data_available.php):

> Data products from Landsat 8 will become available approximately 100
>   days after launch, and will be consistent with the existing standard
>   Level-1 (orthorectified) data products created using Landsat 1 to
>   Landsat 7 data.
>
> The standard Level 1 data and LandsatLook (full-resolution jpg)
>   products will be available for download at no charge from GloVis,
>   EarthExplorer or the LandsatLook Viewer.
>
> Details about processing levels of Landsat data products can be found
>   on http://landsat.usgs.gov/Landsat_Processing_Details.php.

Answer (score 1):

[This post has several sources of Landsat data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20380/what-is-the-best-easiest-way-to-obtain-temporal-landsat-imagery), most notably the USGS EarthExplorer website.

If you need anything later than autumn 2010 you'll have to wait until about mid-May when the USGS makes imagery from the [LDCM](http://landsat.usgs.gov/LDCM_Landsat8.php) publicly available.